# Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer Not Failing Over to Secondary URL

Tags: java, spring-jms, tibco-ems

We have a Spring application that requires a Tibco EMS topic consumer and uses the `org.springframework` utilities for JMS support and uses the `spring-jms-5.2.24.RELEASE.jar` version of Spring JMS.

We configure the URL with two addresses for failover.

```xml
    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
       <property name="environment">
          <props>
             <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://usitdjms-vd3:7222,tcp://usitdjms-vd4:7222</prop>
             <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
             <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${USERNAME}</prop>
             <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${PASSWORD}</prop>
          </props>
       </property>
    </bean>
```

However, when we bring down the vd3 server the code does not failover to vd4. Instead an error is printed continuously and the problem will only resolve when restarting the application.

```
08/15/2023-14:20:19:453 [jmsContainer-1] - ERROR - DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:962 - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'Topic[in_order_perf]' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=54, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to connect to the server at tcp://usitdjms-vd4.ny.cantor.com:7222; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

How do I use Spring's implementation of JMS such that the above two URLS are tried in a round-robin way?  We don't want to have to restart our application if the primary JMS server goes down.

If vd3 fails to connect then vd4 should become connected and vice versa.

Comment: According to the error message Spring is, in fact, attempting to connect to vd4 (i.e. `tcp://usitdjms-vd4.ny.cantor.com:7222`). However, it's getting a "Connection refused" error which indicates that either nothing on vd4 is listening on port `7222` or it's being blocked by a firewall. Are you sure there's an unblocked service listening on `7222` on vd4?

Comment: The vd4 server went down.  That's the reason it can't connect.  What I expect is that the application should then try vd3.

Comment: To be clear, `com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory` (i.e. not Spring) is responsible for supporting multiple targets in its URL. Spring is simply using the JNDI API to perform the lookup. It has no control over implementation details like a round-robin connection policy. It's also worth noting that this is related to JNDI and not JMS specifically.

Comment: In your question you say, "...when we bring down the **vd3** server the code does not failover to **vd4**." This doesn't match what you've noted in your comment. I recommend updating your question to be more clear.

Comment: The feature works when not using the Spring Containers.  For example, If I use native JMS code.  What I need is to understand why.

Comment: The fact that it works outside Spring is an important point. You should explain that in your question, ideally with code where it works.

Comment: I believe that Spring JMS will look up the JMS `ConnectionFactory` in JNDI and continue using that connection factory even if the connection fails. Does the Tibco connection factory implementation support multiple URLs? If so, that should be configured wherever the connection factory is being looked up.

Comment: Keep in mind that JNDI and JMS are 100% independent. It's only by convention that JMS admin objects (e.g. connection factories, destinations, etc.) are looked up in JNDI. Just because you have fail-over configured for your remote JNDI connection doesn't mean that also applies to your JMS connection.

Comment: The URL is specified as a property of JndiTemplate of the form `java.naming.provider.url=url1, url2`.  It sounds like you are saying that a comma separated list of URLs is not supported in the class when specified as a property.  This is a legacy application that has never had to fail over yet the business would have zero tolerance if it failed so I'm looking for a quick way to resolve this.

Comment: I guess replacing Spring's `CachingConnectionFactory` with tibco's `TibjmsConnectionFactory` might be the way to go.

Comment: I don't think that it matters _how_ the comma-separated list of URLs is specified. There's no evidence to suggest that the setting isn't being applied to the `TibjmsInitialContextFactory` instance. My contention is just that Spring isn't going back to the JNDI look-up when the JMS connection fails so it doesn't really matter how the JNDI connection is configured. You need fail-over for the JMS connection, not the JNDI one.

Comment: Spring's `CachingConnectionFactory` is just a wrapper. It's ultimately using a `TibjmsConnectionFactory` implementation anyway (e.g. looked up in JNDI). It is this connection factory that needs to be configured to support fail-over (assuming that's even possible).